# Fazer um get com parâmetros opcionais em GoLang

Tags: golang

Preciso fazer uma api onde pesquisa usando parâmetros query string opcionais.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
func (app *App) getFunctionarys(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    v := r.URL.Query()

    Id := v.Get("Id")
    Name := v.Get("Name")
    Cpf := v.Get("Cpf")
    Role:= v.Get("Role")
    Status := v.Get("Status")

    dbdata := &Funcionary{}
    err := app.Database.QueryRow("SELECT Id,DataCad,Role,Cpf,Name,Uf,Salary,Status FROM `funcionary` WHERE Id = ? OR Name= ? OR Cpf = ? OR Role= ? OR Status = ?", Id, Name, Cpf, Role, Status).Scan(&dbdata.Id, &dbdata.DataCad, &dbdata.Role, &dbdata.Cpf, &dbdata.Name, &dbdata.Uf, &dbdata.Salary, &dbdata.Status)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(dbdata); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Eu tenho 5 registros, mas minha api está retornando apenas o primeiro registro, independente de quais query strings eu colocar. Como eu posso fazer uma api que realize um where com base nos parâmetros opcionais recebidos da requisição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar a função Query ao invés da função QueryRow, QueryRow retorna no máximo um elemento enquanto Query retorna todos do resultado da consulta.

Porém a função Query não retorna um ponteiro de `Row` mas sim um ponteiro de `Rows`, então não é possível usar a função Scan diretamente para ler cada linha do resultado da consulta. Você pode fazer um loop para ler o resultado usando o método `Next` do `Rows`.

No seu caso o código seria algo assim:

```
rows, err := app.Database.Query("SELECT Id,DataCad,Role,Cpf,Name,Uf,Salary,Status FROM `funcionary` WHERE Id = ? OR Name= ? OR Cpf = ? OR Role= ? OR Status = ?", Id, Name, Cpf, Role, Status)

var dbdata []*Funcionary

for rows.Next() {
    funcionary := &Funcionary{}
    err := rows.Scan(&funcionary.Id, &funcionary.DataCad, &funcionary.Role, &funcionary.Cpf, &funcionary.Name, &funcionary.Uf, &funcionary.Salary, &funcionary.Status)
    if err != nil {
      // tratar o erro como vc achar adequado
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dbdata = append(dbdata, funcionary)
  }
```

Caso você esteja interessado em saber mais sobre a função: [documentação oficial da função Query](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.Query).